# Delete EBS volume when termination EC2 Instance, via terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have the below in my .tf file

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "${var.aws_region}"    
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "agent-xvdf" {
  count             = "${var.ec2_count}"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
  kms_key_id        =  "xxxx"  
  encrypted         =   "true"
  size              =   "${var.vol_size_details_xvdf}"
  type              =   "${var.vol_type_details}"
  tags {
    Name        =   "d-drive"
    Owner       =   "${var.ebs_vol_owner}"
    Managed_By  =   "Terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-ec2" {
  depends_on        = ["aws_ebs_volume.agent-xvdf"]
  lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = ["tags"]
   create_before_destroy = true
 }
  count                 = "${var.ec2_count}"
  ami                   = "${data.aws_ami.ami_id.id}"
  iam_instance_profile  = "yyyy"
  instance_type         = "${var.instance_type_details}"  
  tags {
    Owner       = "${var.instance_owner}"
    ServerRole  = "${var.server_details} ${var.ec2_os_flavour}"
    Creator     = "${var.creator_initials}"
    Created     = "TF Creation Time = ${timestamp()}"
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = 
["${data.aws_security_group.vpc_security_group_details.id}"]

   #This is a template provider which exposes chef-cookbook roles during 
bootstrapping process to manage instances or to install software
  #In the below code snippet we have used "teamcity.chef.json" file to 
 mention  Chef cookbook recipes to httpd and TeamCity.
   user_data         = "${file("..\\common\\${var.env_subfolder}\\teamcity.agent.chef.${var.app_instance}.json")}"

  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone}"
  subnet_id         = "${data.aws_subnet.subnet_id_details.id}"

  # This parameter automatically deletes root-volume attached to the instance 
when the instance is terminated.
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = "true"
     volume_size                    = "${var.vol_size_details_sda1}"
     volume_type           = "${var.vol_type_details}"
 }
}

# Below resource will attach/detach "agent-xvdf" volume from AWS Instance i.e. {aws_instance.my-ec2}
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "agent-xvdf" {
  depends_on        = ["aws_ebs_volume.agent-xvdf"]
  count           = "${var.ec2_count}"
  device_name       = "xvdf"
  volume_id         = "${element(aws_ebs_volume.agent-xvdf.*.id, 
count.index)}"
  instance_id       = "${element(aws_instance.my-ec2.*.id, count.index)}"
  force_detach      = "true"  
  skip_destroy      = "false"
    }
```

With the present setup, terraform -pan, -apply, and -destroy works fine and creates and deletes 3 resources respectively.

However when i apply this plan via terraform, and then try to terminate the instance via AWS console the block EBS volume, i.e xvdf does not get deleted automatically.

How can we set this ebs volume to `terminate on instance delete` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ebs_block_device` block within the `aws_instance` resource. This will by default delete the ebs volume when the instance is terminated.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#block-devices

You have to use the above instead of the `aws_volume_attachment` resource.

Comment: EBS, Ephemeral, and Root Block Devices - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs-ephemeral-and-root-block-devices

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer, the `root_block_device` object works on `aws_instance`([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#ebs-ephemeral-and-root-block-devices)) and `aws_launch_configuration`([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_configuration#block-devices)).

```
# provision ec2 directly
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
    ...
     root_block_device {
        delete_on_termination = true
     }
}


# provision ec2 via auto scaling group
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "default" {
     ...
     root_block_device {
         delete_on_termination = true
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,

> root_block_device   {    delete_on_termination = true }

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {

    ami = data.aws_ami.base_ami.id
    count = var.apps_instance_count
    subnet_id = var.apps_subnet_id
    instance_type = var.apps_instance_type
    key_name = var.apps_key_name
    security_groups = ["sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx","sg-xxxxxxxxxx"]
    user_data_replace_on_change = true
    user_data = "${file(var.apps_script_file)}"

  dynamic "root_block_device" {
    for_each = var.root_block_override ? [1] : []
    content {
                delete_on_termination = var.root_block_delete_on_termination
                volume_type = var.root_block_volume_type == "gp3" ? null : var.root_block_iops
                volume_size = var.root_block_volume_size
                throughput = var.root_block_throughput
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please put your comments on where was the issue or when did you find the issue? after adding negative points. thank you so much so to add your comments.